# Can't assign Permission Set License Assignments to a User

Tags: permissions, permission-sets, licenses, fls

I have a User who had a specific FSL Permission Set License assigned. For testing, I deleted this FSL Permission Set License in User edit page and now, I want to revert changes and re-assign the Permission to the user.

Problem is that, now, this Permission does not appear in the list that I can select to assign. I have a list with several Permissions but the permission that I removed 1 hour ago is no longer available.

Why is it happening?

Comment: Maybe someone else has already re-assigned the licence and none is available. Check in `Company Information` do you still have available seats for `FSL Permission Set License ` ?

Comment: Well, it's a small step... This is the info:

Field Service Dispatcher -> Status: Disabled Total Licenses: 0 Used: 25 Remaining: -25

Comment: So it means that licence is not available available. the negative amount probably means either licences are expired or they were courtesy licence provided for a short period of time. You might want to check with your Salesforce account representative to discuss this

Comment: Thank you for your help!